# How to use two id's in an document.getElementById type function.

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to use two insert text boxes ids to form an address for a google map. I can use one Id but the county doesn't effect.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 
</br>
<input type="text" id="search"> Street
</br>
<input type="text" id="search2"> County
</br>
<input type="button" onclick="geocode();" value="Go">

function geocode () {
    geocoder.geocode({
       'address': document.getElementById('search','search2').value
    },
```

Comment: `getElementById` returns single element, it can't accep two parameters. why do you want this?

Comment: I'm trying to create an easy form for a user. I'll be changing the "County" input to a drop down eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getElementById` only returns one element, so you can't use it to access two elements at once.

Access the elements one at a time, and I suppose that you want to put the values together with a separator between them, like a space:

```
'address': document.getElementById('search').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('search2').value
```

Answer (score 0):

passing 2 Ids is not possible. You need something like:

```
'address': document.getElementById('search').value + ', ' + document.getElementById('search').value
```